# Ordered array repetition in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
x = []
a = [1,2,3]
a.each{|i| x<<i; x<<i}
```

Returns:

`[1,1,2,2,3,3]`

Does Ruby have a built-in or quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
n = 2

a.flat_map {|i| [i]*n} # => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2,3]
a = (a*2).sort
#=> [1,1,2,2,3,3]
a.map{ |i| [i,i] }.flatten
#=> [1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a.zip(a).flatten
```

Or, if you need to repeat `n` times,

```
a.zip(*[a]*(n-1)).flatten
```

Inject-based (technically, each_with_object):

```
a.each_with_object([]){|e, acc| n.times{acc << e}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general:

```
Benchmark.measure{1000000.times{x=[]; a.each{|i| x<<i; x<<i}}}
1.530000   0.000000   1.530000 (  1.552974)

Benchmark.measure{1000000.times{a.zip(a).flatten}}
4.140000   0.000000   4.140000 (  4.136788)

Benchmark.measure{1000000.times{a.collect{|i| [i, i]}.flatten}}
4.150000   0.000000   4.150000 (  4.158172)
```

In this specific case fl00r's answer is the fastest:

```
Benchmark.measure{1000000.times{(a*2).sort}}
1.170000   0.000000   1.170000 (  1.173677)
```

Comment: This is not fair. Only 3 members? I bet `sort` could be much more worse than the naive `each`.

Comment: Yes, that is very true. That is why I put it as the winner *in this case*.

Comment: It is indeed the winner in this case, but this benchmark is meaningless. Even if only 3 members and `a = [3,2,1]`, `sort` will be slower than `each`.

Comment: There's no point in comparing performance of the code which doesn't do the same thing (keeping the original order vs. sorting).

Comment: I think you should add the benchmark results at the end of your question instead of posting them as a separate answer.